# htaccess rule: how to parse username from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a user database with unique usernames and I want to set up virtual urls like: `www.mypage.com/nickname`

I've already tried `RewriteRule ^ user.php?name=$1 [L]` but this will also redirect ANY css and js which is not intended.

I was also thinking about parsing the 404 script or something but no idea how I would do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure if that suit you, but I white list the extension that I dont want to redirect

Comment: Google "PHP routing" and you'll find how it's commonly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your rule conditional by adding ( **RewriteCond** ) conditions so that it doesnt rewrite existing files and dirs

```
RewriteEngine on

#don't rewrite existing dirs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#don't rewrite existing files
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#rewrite any uris to "/user.php" excluding files and dirs
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ user.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```